# Clone table from one MariaDB database to another, including defaults, indexes and triggers?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

I want to copy a table, including its indexes and triggers, from one database to another. This is not as straightforward as I had hoped. Here is a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Working_Example) to demonstrate. First, my MariaDB version:

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.29-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
```

Next, the first table:

```
CREATE DATABASE db1;
USE db1;
CREATE TABLE tb1 (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    word VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO tb1 (word) VALUES ('foo');
DELETE FROM tb1 WHERE word='foo';
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER before_word_insert BEFORE INSERT ON tb1 FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        SET NEW.word=TRIM(NEW.word);
        IF NOT (NEW.word REGEXP '^[[:alpha:]]+$') THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '12345' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Invalid word';
        END IF;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
INSERT INTO tb1 (word) VALUES ('foo');
DESCRIBE tb1;
SHOW TRIGGERS;
SHOW INDEX FROM tb1;
```

These last three lines give:

```
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| word  | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

+--------------------+--------+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+---------+----------+----------------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
| Trigger            | Event  | Table | Statement                                                                                                                                                | Timing | Created | sql_mode | Definer        | character_set_client | collation_connection | Database Collation |
+--------------------+--------+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+---------+----------+----------------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
| before_word_insert | INSERT | tb1   | BEGIN SET NEW.word=TRIM(NEW.word); IF NOT (NEW.word REGEXP '^[[:alpha:]]+$') THEN SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Invalid word'; END IF; END | BEFORE | NULL    |          | root@localhost | utf8                 | utf8_general_ci      | latin1_swedish_ci  |
+--------------------+--------+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+---------+----------+----------------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.04 sec)

+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| tb1   |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | id          | A         |           3 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So far, so good. Now, to copy `tb1` to another database (on the same server):

```
CREATE DATABASE db2;
USE db2;
CREATE TABLE db2.tb1 AS SELECT * FROM db1.tb1;
DESCRIBE tb1;
SHOW TRIGGERS;
SHOW INDEX FROM tb1;
```

I had hoped these last three lines would give identical output as they did for `db1`, but they don't:

```
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(11)     | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| word  | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Empty set (0.00 sec)

Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

In other words, `CREATE TABLE db2.tb1 AS SELECT * FROM db1.tb1;`:

- copied the table contents;
- copied the column types;
- **did not copy** the "Key" property;
- **did not copy** the "Default" property;
- **did not copy** the "Extra" property;
- **did not copy** the triggers; and
- **did not copy** the indexes.

**My question:** what would be a concise equivalent to `CREATE TABLE db2.tb1 AS SELECT * FROM db1.tb1;` that **would** copy all of those missing items?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? If you want to copy for example the whole database, use `mysqldump dbName --routines --triggers > outfile.sql` and import that outfile.sql in the new database. It includes everything.

Comment: @Psi, what I want to do is as stated in the title and the question: I want to clone a table from one database to another database, including the default values, triggers and indexes that apply to the source table.

Comment: Yes of course, but only that single table or maybe is that table the only one in the database, so you can clone the whole db.

Comment: In my [MWE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Working_Example), the source table was indeed the only table in the source database, but that was only to keep the example minimal. In real life, the source table is likely to be one among many tables in the source database, and I would not wish to clone the other tables.

Comment: Ok, so dumping the whole db is not a real option then. I again updated my answer on what you could possibly do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE newTable LIKE oldTable
```

should include the indexes and setup, although not the data and triggers.

After that, you need to copy the data:

```
INSERT INTO newTable SELECT * FROM oldTable
```

The triggers are not directly part of the table but rather part of the script management.

You can find the triggers in `information_schema.triggers`. There you can query every trigger set for your table. But I strongly recommend *not to mess around with that table manually*.

Instead, you can read the definition there and create a new trigger using `SHOW CREATE TRIGGER` and `CREATE TRIGGER`. That involves either dynamic sql or a client able to manipulate the sql (which should apply to every client).

If there is a client connected to the source database and to the target database, you can do something like that:

```
SELECT `TRIGGER_NAME` FROM information_schema.triggers WHERE `TRIGGER_SCHEMA` = database() AND `EVENT_OBJECT_TABLE` = oldTableName
```

As you stated in the comments, you can also use

```
SHOW TRIGGERS WHERE `Table` = "oldTable"
```

instead of reading the triggers table. As a side note, these backticks around `Table` are important, because `Table` is a reserved word which is used here in a manner like a column name.

With the trigger names, for each trigger you cast a

```
SHOW CREATE TRIGGER triggerNameFromQueryAbove
```

This gives you the create statement you can use to create the trigger in the new database. But careful: There might be the database name included and the definer, which may not exist in the new database, so you have to strip out that information manually.

For more information on the "triggers" table, read the mysql manual (which also should apply to mariadb): https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/triggers-table.html

Comment: `DESCRIBE tb1;`: db2 result matches db1 result. `SHOW TRIGGERS;`: gives empty set. `SHOW INDEX FROM tb1;`: db2 result matches db1 result. Overall score: 2 out of 3 (vs my 0 out of 3). A definite improvement, so upvoted your answer. Thanks! Would be great to get the triggers copied across too, though.

Comment: As I said, the triggers are not part of the table itself.

Comment: I updated my answer to explain a way on how to get to the triggers. But you still have to create them.

Comment: Thanks. `SHOW TRIGGERS WHERE \`Table\` = 'tb1'` seems to be the most concise way to get all of the triggers applicable to a given table (in this case, table `tb1`). (As an aside, those backticks around `Table` seem to be important: `SHOW TRIGGERS WHERE 'Table' = 'tb1'` does not work. At some point, I will learn why that is the case, but not right now.)

Comment: Thank you, I changed my answer accordingly. The backticks allow the use of reserved words as column names and names containing white spaces such as `\`timestamp\`` or `\`my favorite column\``. As `table` is such a reserved word, but is also used as a pseudo-column name here, you need to enclose it in backticks

Comment: Thanks again; much appreciated. I have accepted your answer. At the moment, I am looking to see if there is a way to get just the `Trigger` column from `SHOW TRIGGERS WHERE \`Table\` = 'tb1'`. If so, that would combine the best of this approach with your `SELECT \`TRIGGER_NAME\` FROM information_schema.triggers ...` approach. But this is a minor refinement. Above all, I am grateful to you for corroborating that copying the triggers requires querying the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` database.

Comment: Well, the result set contains some columns, if you use a client anyway, just use the first column. In fact, there is now way to select only certain columns, it's not even possible to use a `SHOW`-statement as a subquery

Comment: I'm doing this all from MariaDB's `mysql` CLI, in order to better grok MariaDB :)

Comment: In the `mysql` client, you can use `\G` at the end of a command instead of `;` It will lead to a different output format. Maybe this helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at this question, because I have the same question.  I'm a bit dismayed, if there really are no more concise commands to do this.  I want to point out a (perhaps obvious) procedure that will also work.  You could dump the database to a file ("dumpdb1.sql", for example) which is already handy if you're using mysqldump for backups.  You could then of course make a copy of just the relevant text out of dumpdb1.sql that creates tb1, sets its constraints and indexes, and adds its triggers and data, placing this excerpt into a file "buildtb1.sql".  Finally, just run this latter file on db2 and you should get a perfect ***full*** copy of tb1 there.

Also, I see in the MariaDB documentation at: [Tutorialspoint MariaDB Table Cloning](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mariadb/mariadb_table_cloning.htm) they point out the usefulness of the SHOW CREATE TABLE statement in this regard.  It will give a CREATE TABLE statement you can copy and use during this process.  I'm just mentioning this as an alternative to the mysqldump approach, if you don't want to use that.  Of course SHOW CREATE TABLE will not describe triggers, so you would still need to perform a SHOW TRIGGERS process to capture and reproduce those.

Comment: the easiest thing to do is using mysqldump